# Qt using .dll in .dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I want to use one .dll file in another. But it seems like I'm doing something wrong with it. I have two library project ScaraControlGUI and ScaraLogic, and I want to use ScaraLogic into ScaraControlGUI, so I added appropriate lines in ScaraControlGUI's .pro file:

```
DEPENDPATH += . ../ScaraLogic
INCLUDEPATH += ../ScaraLogic
LIBS += -L../ScaraLogic/debug -lScaraLogic
```

And I receive:

```
scaralogic.h: No such file or directory
```

When I want to include this file. I'm sure that this file exist so I bet that I'm doing something wrong around .pro files.

What I'm doing wrong ? Adding ScaraControlGUI .dll to main executable project works fine like this.

Thanks in advace for help.

Comment: Where `scaralogic.h` lives and how do you include it in your ScaraControlGUI project?

Comment: Hi, scaralogic.h lives in ScaraLogic main project directory, I thnik that this img explain more https://i.gyazo.com/80b8f92b026940da91867736387afb65.png and I include this file like this: #include <scaralogic.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. My ScaraControlGUI subproject was building properly. Problem was in my main project ScaraControl and to solve this I needed to add LIBS and INCLUDEPATH too.

Answer (score 1):

As your header is in `ScaraLogic/Headers` directory, you have to include it as `#include <Headers/scaralogic.h>`, or, which is better, set `INCLUDEPATH` as

```
DEPENDPATH += . ../ScaraLogic
INCLUDEPATH += ../ScaraLogic/Headers
LIBS += -L../ScaraLogic/debug -lScaraLogic
```

in the project file, and still use `#include <scaralogic.h>`.

Comment: Header lives in ScaraLogic/Headers but your solution isn't working for me, I still get same error.